# Repository pattern dependency injection using Dapper

Tags: asp.net-core

My `Startup.cs` contains 40 repositories:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IXRepository, XRepository>();
... 40 more lines ...
```

I'm trying to find a way to have this mess in a single line, but I'm failing miserably to put my head around this, I have several methods that are not available in the interface. Can someone provide some help? I understand why it is not working, it does not have a concrete repository, but I'm no closer to making this work.

`InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type...`

```
// IRepository.cs
public interface IRepository
{
}

// IUserRepository.cs
public interface IUserRepository : IRepository
{
    User ReadToken(string email, string password);
}

// BaseRepository.cs
public class BaseRepository : IDisposable
{
    protected IDbConnection PostgreSQL;

    public BaseRepository(IDbConnection postgreSQL)
    {
        PostgreSQL = postgreSQL;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

// UserRepository.cs
public class UserRepository : BaseRepository, IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(IDbConnection postgreSQL) : base(postgreSQL)
    {
    }

    public User ReadToken(string email, string password)
    {
        object parameters;
        string sql;

        parameters = new
        {
            email,
            password
        };

        sql =
        @"
        SELECT
            user_id AS id,
            token
        FROM users
        WHERE
            email = @email AND
            password = CRYPT(@password, password) AND
            active = TRUE;
        ";

        var user = base.PostgreSQL.Query<User>(sql, parameters).SingleOrDefault();

        if (user == null)
            throw new UnauthorizedException("User", "User not found.");

        return user;
    }
}

// UsersController.cs
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    protected IUserRepository UserRepository;

    public UsersController(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        UserRepository = userRepository;
    }
}

// Startup.cs
services.AddTransient<IRepository, BaseRepository>();
```

Comment: What you are looking for is called `convention based registration`. For example you can tell that you want register all classes which ends with `Repository` as the interfaces they implement. Unfortunately built-in ASP.NET Core IOC is very limited and doesn't provide such functionality. So you can either wrap it up with your code which scans all referenced assemblies, look for classes matched by pattern and add them to ServiceCollection or you can use different IOC implementation that provide this functionality e.g. Autofac

Comment: Is there a way to change my implementation in such a way to provide a one line solution?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that you can implement generic interface and it's implementation of entity types and then register it like `services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>))`, but in that case you will not have too much flexibility.

Comment: Yes, I'm deep in convention based registration now. I'm pretty sure is the way to go. Thx bro. I suggest you post as an answer. I think this could help other people. I have read about generic implementations a lot, and not a single word about convenction based registration.

Comment: please mark one of the answer as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor)

It offers assembly scanning and decoration extensions for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

All those repositories can be summed up to something like this:

```
services.Scan(x => x.FromAssemblyOf<IAnAssemblyRegistrationMarker>()
        .AddClasses(filter => filter.AssignableTo(typeof(IRepository)))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .WithScopedLifetime());
```

`IAnAssemblyRegistrationMarker` is an empty interface to point at the assembly (project) you want to scan

`AddClasses` Adds all public, non-abstract classes from the selected assemblies that matches the requirements specified in the

`AsImplementedInterfaces` Registers each matching concrete type as all of its implemented interfaces

`WithScopedLifetime` Registers each matching concrete type with Scoped Lifetime (You also have `WithSingletonLifetime` and `WithTransientLifetime`)

The only requirement in the code example above is that the repositories implement `IRepository` in order for you to target only the necessary items.

Disclaimer: I am not associated with Scrutor in any way. I just like the thing.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called `convention based registration`. This gives you ability register all types which for example ends with `Repository`  as the interfaces they implement. However the built-in ASP.NET Core IOC is very lightweight and doesn't provide such functionality. So you can either wrap it up with your code which scans all referenced assemblies, look for types by a pattern and then add them to ServiceCollection or you can use different IOC implementation that provides this functionality and supports .Net Core e.g. Autofac, StructureMap etc.